# How to go back one day and find the data

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Basically, i want to go back one day and find the data using query...

This is what i have so far:

```
 select price from SAMPLE_DATA 
 where trunc(date) = '11-FEB-13'
```

However, when i tried using:

```
 select price from SAMPLE_DATA 
 where trunc(date) = trunc(date-1)
```

this doesn't return anything. So is there anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you're asking it to find you records where `business_date` is exactly equal to `business_date - 1`, which is like asking for rows where `12 = 11`, and that's pretty unlikely to return any results. :-)

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag, as your comment to @JC  mentions an Oracle error (and your subject mentions SQL Server). Please use the tags and words that actually apply to your question instead of just grabbing any that appear. Also, `sql` is `structured QUERY language`, so there's no need for a separate `query` tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing the date in the record with the date previous to the date in the record. At no point are you using the current date as a reference. Try this instead:

```
select mid_price from SAMPLE_DATA where trunc(business_date) = trunc(sysdate-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using your way however it gives me an error: ORA-00904: "CURDATE": invalid identifier

Comment: you're using Oracle? You have a mysql tag on the question. Try `sysdate` instead of `curdate()`